# How can I extend javascript String without getting a JSHint Issue?

Tags: javascript, string, jshint

Hi I am extending String using prototype but JSHint throws a warning:

> Extending prototype of native object: 'String'.

How should I be tackling this? I assume the warning is down to this method being considered bad practice.

```
String.prototype.decodeHTML = function() {

    return $('<div>', {html: '' + this}).html();

};
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

UPDATE This does actually work:

Here's the solution for those that want it.

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "decodeHTML", {
    value: function () {
         return $('<div>', {html: '' + this}).html();
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm not getting the warning

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See JSLint Docs: https://jslinterrors.com/extending-prototype-of-native-object. You should use

```
Object.defineProperty(String.prototype, "decodeHTML", ...)
```

instead.

Comment: I have seen this however upon trying it, I seemed to break the function causing it to simply do nothing.

Answer (score 1):

The warning in question should only be issued when the [`freeze` option](http://jshint.com/docs/options/#freeze) is enabled. You can disable that option for the relevant block (or file) by using a directive comment:

```
/*jshint freeze: false */
String.prototype.decodeHTML = function() {

    return $('<div>', {html: '' + this}).html();

};
```